# Leaflet kmz stops loading other kmz files if gets XHR 404 while fetching remote file in any one of kmz's

Tags: leaflet, javascript, kml, kmz, layer-to-kml

Referring to https://github.com/Raruto/leaflet-kmz

Here is my leafllet kmz code:

```
<script>
  var map = L.map('map', {
    preferCanvas: true // recommended when loading large layers.
  });
  map.setView(new L.LatLng(43.5978, 12.7059), 5);

  var OpenTopoMap = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
   maxZoom: 17,
   attribution: 'Map data: &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org /copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, <a href="http://viewfinderpanoramas.org">SRTM</a> | Map style: &copy; <a href="https://opentopomap.org">OpenTopoMap</a> (<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>)',
opacity: 0.90
  });
  OpenTopoMap.addTo(map);

  // Instantiate KMZ layer (async)
  var kmz = L.kmzLayer().addTo(map);

  kmz.on('load', function(e) {
   control.addOverlay(e.layer, e.name);
   // e.layer.addTo(map);
  });

 // Add remote KMZ files as layers (NB if they are 3rd-party servers, they MUST have CORS enabled)
  kmz.load('https://raruto.github.io/leaflet-kmz/examples/regions.kmz'); //Loads successfully
  kmz.load('https://raruto.github.io/leaflet-kmz/examples/blah.kmz'); //404 error
  kmz.load('https://raruto.github.io/leaflet-kmz/examples/globe.kmz'); //Won't get loaded

  var control = L.control.layers(null, null, { collapsed:false }).addTo(map);
</script>
```

Referring to the code above:

kmz.load('https://raruto.github.io/leaflet-kmz/examples/blah.kmz');
ends in **404 error** and stops subsequent loading of kmz.

kmz.load('https://raruto.github.io/leaflet-kmz/examples/globe.kmz') doesn't get loaded because of 404 error while loading blah.kmz file. I don't want the code to break in case of 404 error in any of the kmz files. I want to ignore 404 error and proceed to loading of next kmz.
How that can be implemented here?

Answer (score 1):

There is no proper error handling in `leaflet-kmz` plugin. To correct this it would require modification of plugin code on several places.

Quick and dirty trick to make plugin work as you want requires only adding one line in the `loadFile` function at the beginning of `leaflet-kmz-src.js`:

```
function loadFile(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    xhr.onload = () => {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4 && (xhr.status === 200 || xhr.status === 0)) {
        resolve(xhr.response || xhr.responseText);
      } else {
        console.warn("Error " + xhr.status + " while fetching remote file: " + url);
        resolve('');  // added line
      }
    };
    xhr.onerror = () => reject("Error " + xhr.status + " while fetching remote file: " + url);
    xhr.send();
  });
}
```

In the case of nonexistent `.kml` file, this will cause the following error in the console:

```
XML Parsing Error: no root element found
Location: http://localhost/LeafletExamples/kml.html
Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

but the execution will continue anyway.